# Index/Small with multiple criteria, multiple results, and wild card

Tags: excel, indexing, excel-formula

I am basing my question on the instructions that I found at this link
[on eImagine](http://eimagine.com/how-to-return-multiple-match-values-in-excel-using-index-match-or-vlookup/).

I followed the instructions to return lists based on one criteria item. It worked well. The initial formula is below:

`{=IF(ISERROR(INDEX('Data 6.26.18'!$A$2:$AR$6000,SMALL(IF('Data 6.26.18'!$V$2:$V$6000=Summary!$A22,ROW('Data 6.26.18'!$V$2:$V$6000)-1),COLUMN()-3),14)),"",INDEX('Data 6.26.18'!$A$2:$AR$6000,SMALL(IF('Data 6.26.18'!$V$2:$V$6000=Summary!$A22,ROW('Data 6.26.18'!$V$2:$V$6000)-1),COLUMN()-3),14))}`

However, when I tried to add a second criteria item, things didn't work as well. I assume that the SMALL function doesn't work well with AND statements, and piling wild card logic on top of that might not help. The formula that I attempted is below:

```
{=IF(ISERROR(INDEX(Current!$A$2:$AQ$6000,SMALL(IF(AND(Current!$V$2:$V$6000=Summary!$A17,Current!$S$2:$S$6000="*Open/Active*"),ROW(Current!$V$2:$V$6000)-1),COLUMN()-3),14)),"",INDEX(Current!$A$2:$AQ$6000,SMALL(IF(AND(Current!$V$2:$V$6000=Summary!$A17,Current!$S$2:$S$6000="*Open/Active*"),ROW(Current!$V$2:$V$6000)-1),COLUMN()-3),14))}
```

Can anyone help me understand what I might need to do make this work? For clarity, I pulled these two formulas from different cells that match on different reference cells ($A$17 and $A$22). Otherwise, I am hoping to make the latter input formula work for both cells.

Please let me know if further background on the referenced spreadsheet would help.

Comment: Did you ask elmagine?

Comment: `AND` does not work in array formulas so instead of `AND(x=x,y=y)` do `(x=x)*(y=y)`

Comment: @SolarMike I believe someone asked a similar question there and the author wasn't able to answer it.

Comment: @ScottCraner Thanks, that's helpful. I really to learn more about array formulas.

Answer (score 0):

You may try to incorporate another `IF()` within your `IF()` since `AND()` doesn't work with arrays. So basically, it would look like:

```
IF(Current!$V$2:$V$6000=Summary!$A17,IF(Current!$S$2:$S$6000="*Open/Active*",....
```

Or you could as well try:

```
IF((Current!$V$2:$V$6000=Summary!$A17)*(Current!$S$2:$S$6000="*Open/Active*"),...
```

Tested the first one as working, but haven't really tried the second one. It would be great if the second one did work since it's easier to understand.

Comment: Thanks. I tried the second method you listed, as I wasn't sure how to structure the IF statements of the first. It doesn't seem to be working correctly, as the output is blank across the board. Is there something wrong in the way that I wrote the formula?
'{=IF(ISERROR(INDEX(Current!$A$2:$AQ$6000,SMALL(IF((Current!$V$2:$V$6000=Summary!$A17)*(Current!$S$2:$S$6000="*Open/Active*"),ROW(Current!$V$2:$V$6000)-1),COLUMN()-3),14)),"",INDEX(Current!$A$2:$AQ$6000,SMALL(IF((Current!$V$2:$V$6000=Summary!$A17)*(Current!$S$2:$S$6000="*Open/Active*"),ROW(Current!$V$2:$V$6000)-1),COLUMN()-3),14))}'